# System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am hosting .net core applicaton on server but when I try to run the application it throws exception in windows logs:

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 
'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception.
 ---> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIInitialize(IntPtr pmo)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIInitialize()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..ctor()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObjectFactory.get_EncryptionOptions()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..ctor(Boolean MARS, Boolean fAsynchronous)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.CreateAndOpenConnection()
   at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseConnection[T](DbConnection dedicatedConnection, Func`2 func)
   at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseConnection(DbConnection dedicatedConnection, Action`1 action)
   at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.Initialize()
   at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString, SqlServerStorageOptions options)
   at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at Hangfire.SqlServerStorageExtensions.UseSqlServerStorage(IGlobalConfiguration configuration, String nameOrConnectionString)
   at SedonaOne.ServerConfig.HangfireConfig.<>c.<ConfigureServices>b__0_0(IGlobalConfiguration config) in E:\AlarmBiller\SedonaX\SedonaOne\ServerConfig\HangfireConfig.cs:line 22
   at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<AddHangfire>b__0(IServiceProvider provider, IGlobalConfiguration config)
   at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<AddHangfire>b__10(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.ThrowIfNotConfigured(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateBackgroundJobServerHostedService(IServiceProvider provider, JobStorage storage, IEnumerable`1 additionalProcesses, BackgroundJobServerOptions options)
   at Hangfire.HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<AddHangfireServerInner>b__0(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitNoCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at SedonaOne.Program.Run(String[] args, Boolean asGenericHost) in E:\AlarmBiller\SedonaX\SedonaOne\Program.cs:line 80
   at SedonaOne.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\AlarmBiller\SedonaX\SedonaOne\Program.cs:line 21
```

I tried many ways to solve this but failed. I am using Windows Server 2019. I have checked SQL connection string but that is also correct one so I am not sure why its failing to connect with SQL. Even I am unsure if its sql connection error or after connetion error

Comment: Does this happen when you run locally? Also, can you post all the dependencies?

Comment: Thanks for your reposnse. 

No, it occurs on server when I publish .net core application on windows server 2019. Also should I post names of depedencies or what?

Comment: did you have any chance finding a solution for this error?

Comment: I was using windows authentication so changed it to SQL authentication with new user and assigned all permissions of sql db to that user, it started working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously I was using windows authentication so I changed it to sql authentication in connection string. I have created new sql user and assigned permissions of sql db to that user. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following dependencies fixed the problem for me:

- System.Data.SqlClient
- Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

I was also needing to add `TrustServerCertificate=True` to my connection strings to trust the server certificate. but it had nothing to see with the original error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the bitness-Setting for the IIS AppPool.

Enable 32-Bit Applications => False (for 64-Bit .NET Core applications)

[AppPool Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vLlb.png)